# Publishing an app on playstore as an organization?

Tags: android, google-account

When I go to: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

It now needs me to sign in, It has my personal account there with my details, 
It does give this statement:

> If you would like to use a different account, you can choose from the following options below. If you are an organisation, consider registering a new Google account rather than using a personal account.

I click Create a new Google account, but it asks for first and last name etc.

Surely I need to create a Different type of account? Such as an Organization account? Where it has details about the organization name etc?

Do I need to create a normal account and just put the organizations name in where they want the First name? How am I meant to proceed ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the process of publishing applications.

Comment: Does my title not reflect that correctly?

Comment: It's not about your title being correct or not it's about your question being offtopic on stackoverflow.